# Change the confirm modal in Rails 6 link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to change the `{ confirm: 'Are you sure you want to report this challenge?' }` alert thing, like a modal in the middle of the screen with an input where I can write something?

```
<%= link_to(report_post_path(@post), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to report this post?' }) do %>
```

Or I have remove the `data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to report this post?' }` and make the modal myself?

Answer (score 1):

you can try gem [data-confirm-modal](https://github.com/ifad/data-confirm-modal), it is have good documentation.
Also you can check any solution from gists, I think it will be good [gist](https://gist.github.com/trey/1765619).
Third option to search other solutions on google with request **rails confirmation modal**. But for me the gem the best solution